# How to merge the solution sets of inequality involving Trigonometric functions?

Tags: inequalities

```
In[21]:= FunctionDomain[Log[10, 3 - 4 (Sin[x])^2], x]

Out[21]= 
C[1] \[Element] 
  Integers && (1/3 (-\[Pi] + 6 \[Pi] C[1]) < x < 
    1/3 (\[Pi] + 6 \[Pi] C[1]) || 
   1/3 (2 \[Pi] + 6 \[Pi] C[1]) < x < 1/3 (4 \[Pi] + 6 \[Pi] C[1]))
```

Drawing with Trigonometric functions lines

[image]

From the image, it can be seen that the final edges of the two corners are on the same straight line, and the merged result in the image can be obtained. How to merge the results of software calculations?

Comment: There was a similar question recently. I don't recall if it was solved...sry

Comment: But the two domains do not give same result? screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meuQr.png)